# What's wrong with my Android virtual device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt

I tried to emulate the app on android virtual device emulator. It started booting up and then just stopped. That emulator does not work at all. I tried almost 10 times now.
The errors I'm getting are

```
[2014-04-15 13:41:25 - Emulator] NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument
[2014-04-15 13:41:25 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section nand_dev
[2014-04-15 13:42:42 - learningandroid] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.learningandroid.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

How to solve the issue?

LAST ONE WAS DISCONNECTED BY ME.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse and `AVD`. If it doesn't work after that, create a new `AVD` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You might try these 3 things (and probably in this order):

1. If your AVD paths have spaces, try avoiding them.
2. Try re-creating your AVD and even the virtual devices (with special care to configure them accordingly: memory, etc.).
3. Re-install SDK and try using a fresh Eclipse copy

Answer (score 0):

Try genyMotion its a free emulator which comes with Eclipse Extension and Many more features.
http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Delete your old `avd`, and try to re-creating a new `avd`
2. Keep your eyes on config when you creating such as memory ...etc.

Good luck.