# Error Related Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, eclipse

This is link for android virtual device it shows grid menu of icons and applications, but my virtual device is showing **text=No Events** .. what can i do?

its showing No Events after run.. please do helpful

[image]

**logcat**

```
2014-09-10 17:11:48 - Emulator] NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument 
2014-09-10 17:11:48 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section nand_dev 
2014-09-10 17:13:04 - RealEstate_HBI] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.Vivek.realestate_hbi.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

Comment: pls make your question more clear

Answer (score 0):

issue already exist :
[What's wrong with my Android virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078721/whats-wrong-with-my-android-virtual-device)

> You might try these 3 things (and probably in this order):
>
> ```
> If your AVD paths have spaces, try avoiding them.
> Try re-creating your AVD and even the virtual devices (with special care to configure them accordingly: memory, etc.).
> Re-install SDK and try using a fresh Eclipse copy
> ```